# How to draw over canvas with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on building my first mini JS game and working through the w3schools tutorial but can't even get my first component to load in the codepen preview area. This has been a very disappointing first couple steps. I know myGameArea loads fine as it's styled to pop but I just want a simple red square to draw on top of it.

```
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function(){
    this.context.clearRect(0,0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}


function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function(){
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGameArea.update();
}

<button onClick="startGame()">
Press
</button>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: You don't appear to have defined `myGameArea.update()`

Comment: Did you mean `myGamePiece.update()`?

Comment: Yep, an hr and half of combing through the code and didn't see that small typo. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateGameArea` calls `myGameArea.clear()` and then tries to call `update` which doesn't exist. Are you not getting an error when this runs?

You probably want to call `myGamePiece.update()`.